# How to rout a form entry back to a site homepage not the associated list

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, list-form

**Idea:**
The form upon submitting or canceling should take you back to the site homepage.

**Current Issue:**
For some reason upon submitting or canceling on the current one I have created using a call to action web part to open a new form it takes you to the SharePoint list associated with the form. I want it to rout back to the homepage that the call to action web part renders.

Answer (score 0):

This is how in the image below to fix this issue
[image: Items to cover to fix]